# when updating the joint table the parent record is deleted

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

We are developping an application with .NET Core and EF Core with Code First so we are using Migrations to create and expand the database. 
The application will be used to setup conventions. So with speakers, sessions and different subjects.
I have two entities. WishlistSpeaker and Track and they form a Many to Many relationship. With Fluent API I created a join table with the ID's from both tables. Now when I create a wishlistSpeaker with a list of tracks it is neatly stored in the WishlistspeakerTrack join table. When i try to update that WishlistSpeaker and add or remove a track both the speaker and the WishlistSpeakerTracks are deleted. I don't see any errors in my debugging.

I tried changing the onDelete and OnUpdate actions in the migration and then reapplying them.  Seeing as I don't get errors in my Code i think it has something to do with the DB so I spent most of my time searching there.

The WishlistSpeaker Entity

```
    public class WishlistSpeaker
    {
        [Key]
        public int WishlistSpeakerId { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int EventID { get; set; }

        public string Company { get; set; }

        public string Mail { get; set; }

        public string Country { get; set; }

        public string Twitter { get; set; }

        public List<WishlistSpeakerTrack> WishlistSpeakerTracks { get; set; }

        public int StatusId { get; set; }

        public Status Status { get; set; }

        public string LinkedIn { get; set; }
    }
```

The Track entity

```
    public class Track
    {
        [Key]
        public int TrackId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string TrackName { get; set; }

        public int EventId { get; set; }

        public Event Event { get; set; }

        public List<WishlistSpeakerTrack> WishlistSpeakerTracks { get; set; }
    }
```

This is the entity created for the JoinTable

```
    public class WishlistSpeakerTrack
    {
        [Key]
        public int TrackId { get; set; }

        public Track Track { get; set; }

        [Key]
        public int WishlistSpeakerId { get; set; }

        public WishlistSpeaker WishlistSpeaker { get; set; }
    }
```

This is what is created in the migration. The OnDelete is now set to NoAction but it used to be Restrict

```
 migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "WishlistSpeakerTrack",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    TrackId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                    WishlistSpeakerId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_WishlistSpeakerTrack", x => new { x.TrackId, x.WishlistSpeakerId });
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_WishlistSpeakerTrack_Track_TrackId",
                        column: x => x.TrackId,
                        principalTable: "Track",
                        principalColumn: "TrackId",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.NoAction);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_WishlistSpeakerTrack_WishlistSpeakers_WishlistSpeakerId",
                        column: x => x.WishlistSpeakerId,
                        principalTable: "WishlistSpeakers",
                        principalColumn: "WishlistSpeakerId",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.NoAction);
                });
```

I wan't to update my WishlistSpeaker and the JoinTable Without both getting deleted.

Comment: The behavior you are explaining is hard to believe. Even with `onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade` which is the default for this type of relationship, the cascade delete works other way around - from primary tables to join table. Needs [mcve].

Comment: When I update the user, like change his first name. The speaker doesn't get deleted it's only when i Add or Remove tracks

Comment: If you are adding / removing `WishlistSpeakerTrack` class instances, make sure navigation properties `Track` and `WishlistSpeaker` are either set to  `null` (and only `TrackId` and `WishlistSpeakerId` are filled in) or *attached* to the context *before* calling `Add` / `Remove`.

Comment: I tried both ways but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I did both and neither works.
I think i found my problem. In my ContextModelSnapshot it is still set to `onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade`
How do i change this?

```
modelBuilder.Entity("Oganize.Api.Core.Entities.WishlistSpeakerTrack", b =>
                {
                    b.HasOne("Oganize.Api.Core.Entities.Track", "Track")
                        .WithMany("WishlistSpeakerTracks")
                        .HasForeignKey("TrackId")
                        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

                    b.HasOne("Oganize.Api.Core.Entities.WishlistSpeaker", "WishlistSpeaker")
                        .WithMany("WishlistSpeakerTracks")
                        .HasForeignKey("WishlistSpeakerId")
                        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
                });
```